# Getting the V8 engine version in Opera browser

Tags: v8, opera

It is easy to get V8 version in chrome by typing `chrome://version/`. But how to do it in opera?

Thanks for any answer or advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be exposed directly, but one possible workaround is:

- go to opera://about, and look at the Chrome version in the user agent string, e.g. "Chrome/65.0.3325.162"
- go to [omahaproxy.appspot.com](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com) and use the "Version Information" box to map the Chrome version to a V8 version, e.g. 65.0.3325.162 has V8 version 6.5.254.36.

Fine print: I don't know how accurate the user agent information is, i.e. whether the Opera binary is actually built from exactly the sources of the indicated Chrome version. But even if it isn't, the steps above should give a good approximation.